# Do any of the things happening on this world actually have a chance of happening? And if they do, how long would humankind survive?

Tags: internal-consistency, post-apocalypse, alternate-earth, climate-change

In this world, global warming has reached a tipping point. The equator has reached temperatures well over 212 degrees Fahrenheit (100 Celsius, 373 Kelvin), resulting in the "Boiling Sea". Global companies saw an opportunity to connect the wrecked world after massive flash floods by damming off parts of the equator and building equatorial train systems on it. Underneath these giant systems, small, climate-controlled submarines are now called home by thousands of refugees from a radical pirate group called the Bermudans (named after the Bermuda Triangle) who roam the new oceans, which now take up even more of the Earth.

Humans have created climate-controlled suits to help them survive the heat, but many series of earthquakes have separated the continents into cracked collections of islands with thin rivers in between each. In North and South America, the islands are wider apart and people now have with chalky or ashen skin due to the old eruption. New wars over territory have arisen, but a new effort, headed by the New United State-Isles, called the Armada, has relieved much of the world from governments of their own, leading the the U.S.I/Armada to take over much of the world.

Is ANY of this remotely possible? The flooding, the islands, the eruption, the human race SURVIVING this. Oh, and nuclear war has somehow never happened ;).

Comment: This will most likely be taken down as "too broad". You might want to check this out https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask . On the subject of your actual question, mankind will be killed by a wall of steam and the following runaway greenhouse effect. With your premise of 100 C hot oceans, they will evaporate rapidly, boiling everyone alive and then the water will drive up the temperature even further since it is a potent greenhouse gas. Just look up whether or not people can survive on Venus and you got your answer.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by "a wall of steam". If this happened gradually, it is possible that mankind would create aforementioned climate control suits and distribute them (at least in first-world countries) to the general population. Additionally, the vapor might eventually circulate and rain back down near the poles. I think you need to explain how you think that water vapor is a "potent greenhouse gas".

Comment: By the way, things do not happen instantaneously on Earth.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  Please take a moment to [learn more about our culture](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) and take our [tour]. Please read our meta posts about [high concept questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868) and [open-ended questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6654). The problems with quetions like this are they are not objective and tend to be very broad. Understand that [SE is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107#92110).

Comment: Having said all that... Why are you asking the question?  I've been hearing environmentalists claim irreversible climate change "in the next 5 years" since the 70s.  My point is that we know so little about planetary climatology that we have trouble predicting tomorrow's weather - much less the catastrophic conditions you describe - so, yes, it's all possible and believable.  But what's the point of the question?  To give you a brash example, do you need our permission to write your story?  (Keep in mind that much, much, less sensible stuff has made authors fortunes - Star Trek for instance.)

Comment: No, but I wanted to see if it was remotely feasible. I now see that it is not.

Comment: OK, what you wanted to do was as a [tag:reality-check] question.  When you do that (and we hope you continue to contribute to the site), you present a complete scenario and tag the question [tag:reality-check].  There's not actually a need to ask a question with that tag, because all you're doing is inviting us to critique the scenario.  Click on that tag link to learn more.  Cheers.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you.

Comment: We don't by custom designate an accepted answer for 24 hours, as this may discourage other (better) answers, it's fine to withdraw and then re-award the bonus later. That being said - you probably won't get a better answer, so - it's up to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's be clear; if equatorial temperatures are already around 100<sup>o</sup>C, humans have been dead for some time. There's absolutely no chance of humans surviving in a world of those temperatures, even with climate controlled suits, and even if they DID, they'd no longer have the social and economic structures to achieve the mega-engineering projects you're describing.

Current climate science is worried about the average temperature on Earth rising by a mere 5<sup>o</sup>C, which would have devastating impacts on life in both the sea and on land - many believe that an increase of 10<sup>o</sup> is unsurviveable by humans; certainly our current model of society and our numbers would not survive such increases.

We boil water to kill off germs in it already. This is because very little life outside of some very specific extremophiles can survive temperatures above the boiling point of water. More complex life is going to have an even harder time of surviving those temperatures.

I should also point out that if the equator has reached boiling point, then there are no 'flash floods' happening because most of the water has boiled off by draining into that area at some point, and any water that still exists around the poles is going still be very hot making it impossible to sustain life like phytoplankton which generate most of the oxygen in the world's oceans, also making larger more complex marine life impossible, and that doesn't even start to cover the impact on land based plant life and the commensurate reductions in O<sub>2</sub> levels that would ensue.

In short, your world has been dead for a long time before the oceans at the equator boil.

Comment: Perhaps not entirely dead.  Hydrothermal vent communities might do fairly well.